# Secure to secure proxy with Apache 2.4 and separate hosts

Tags: apache, ssl, proxy, cross-domain

I am trying to proxy a SCORM entry point on my LMS to the content on another LMS. The manifest resource href looks like:

https://example.com/training/rest/of/the/content/link?key=value

And in my httpd.conf, I have the following:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
RewriteRule ^proxy:.* - [F]
ProxyPass /training/ https://theirsite.com/
ProxyPassReverse /training/ https://theirsite.com/

<Location /training/>
    SetOutputFilter proxy-html
    Header add referer https://theirsite.com/
    Header set Accept-Ranges none
    RequestHeader set referer https://theirsite.com/
    RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
    ProxyHTMLEnable on
    ProxyHTMLExtended on
    ProxyHTMLURLMap / ppt/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap https://example.com/ ppt/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap https://example.com/training/ ppt/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap ppt/ https://example.com/training/
</Location>
```

The problems I am having are this:

- The value in my manifest href is correctly hitting the content host (so my proxy values are correct), but are not returning to https://example.com/training/, they are returning to https://example.com, which leads to my next problem.
- I am having to map all of the URLs when the body returns to me, which is not a problem, except the client host is actually using a third-party for a particular JS library, and mapping / to a standardized value so I can then re-standardize the entire body back to https://example.com/training/, is breaking that particular link.

I have tried various rewrites and substitutions, but I feel I may be missing a key component on this proxying business :/